# How to fix transportation network connectivity problem?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, transportation, connectivity-analysis

I am using network analysis in ArcGIS to conduct a health-related analysis of limited resource country. the quality of the road network layer is not high, with many connectivity problems between the road lines.

Probably there is no way to obtain a higher quality layer. What is the recommended way of testing and fixing the transportation network connectivity?

I use ArcGIS and R mainly but happy to learn other tools if needed.

Comment: What have you tried? You could start your research with Snap tool or Integrate tool